# SurfaceInkCanvas scales strokes when painting out of bounds

Tags: c#, pixelsense

I have a `ScatterView` that contains an image over which I should be able to draw.

```
<s:ScatterView HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="desk" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <s:ScatterViewItem Width="200" Height="200">
        <Grid>
            <Image Name="img1" Source="/Resources/Desert.jpg"/>
            <Viewbox>
                <s:SurfaceInkCanvas Name="cvs1"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
    </s:ScatterViewItem>
</s:ScatterView>
```

I noticed that whenever I draw an ink trail towards the border of the image, the strokes on the ink canvas are scaled down to make room for more stuff. I do *not* want these strokes to be zoomed out. How can I change this behavior?

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n__YfQ0lxKc) is a video that shows what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. This behavior is caused by the fact that I hadn't defined a `Width` and `Height` on the `SurfaceInkCanvas`. This should do the trick:

```
<s:SurfaceInkCanvas Name="cvs1" Width="200" Height="200" />
```